# MSSQLSERVER checkbox cannot be checked when install SQL Server 2008 SP2

Tags: sql-server-2008

[image]

I want upgrade my SQL Server 2008 by installing SP2, however, I could not check the instance name as snapshot shows. I can confirm this service is running as I have checked in Administration tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message on the right is pretty clear - you have SQL Server **2008** (v10.0.1600.22) installed, and you're trying to apply the Service Pack 2 for SQL Server **2008 R2** (v10.50.1600.1) on top of it.

SQL Server **2008** and **2008 R2** are two **different** versions of SQL Server! You cannot do this. You need to download Service Pack 2 for SQL Server **2008** (not **2008 R2**!)

Answer (score 0):

From the error screen on the top right says the version is mismatched have you tried using windows update to install service packs?

Comment: Also I think you are trying to apply SQL 2008 R2 to a SQL 2008 instance try this download page http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12548

Comment: Agreed - you need to obtain the service pack for SQL Server 2008 (10.0...) , not 2008 R2 (10.50...). You probably want to install the latest service pack, which for 2008 is Service Pack *4* https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/968382